# How to assign internal names ("programmatic"/cryptic and non-visible for the form participant) for each question in a google form

Tags: google-forms

Is there any way to set question cryptic-name/variable in addition to the question visible to one answering the form.

What I need is that when I export forms questions to google sheet I can programmatically match questions and answers to do particular calculations.

Currently, column names (headers) are equal to elaborate questions that use sees, and apart of being cumbersome, every time I slightly change the text of the question, I have to propagate the change into the program. The position of the question, as an identifier, is not acceptable either.

Comment: this is too abstract. you could resolve this in many ways. like numbering questions and then vlookuping it with formula

Comment: Thanks, @user0, but your suggestion is not matching the requirements presented in the question. Now I also rewrote the question title to clarify better.

The lookup data/names (in your case numbers) are 1) visible to participants, 2) changing order of the questions ->  changing the numbers -> breaking link (or worst: incorrectly mapping) with the evaluation code.

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms doesn't include a feature to assign a custom technical name (hidden from the user) but it assign automatically two:

- Item id
- Entry id

The first is available through Google Apps Script , the second is used on the prefilled URL. Note: grid questions have an entry id for each row.

Idea:

- Use the Properties Service / Sheets Developer Metadata to save a map of your technical names with the Item / Entry ids